# recursive function python, create function that generates all numbers that have same sum N

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to code a recursive function that generates all the lists of numbers < N who's sum equal to N in python
This is the code I wrote :

```
def fn(v,n):
    N=5
    global vvi
    v.append(n) ;
    if(len(v)>N):
        return
    if(sum(v)>=5):
        if(sum(v)==5): vvi.append(v)

    else:
        for i in range(n,N+1):
            fn(v,i)
```

this is the output I get

```
vvi
Out[170]: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I tried same thing with c++ and it worked fine

Comment: python and c++ are both different languages with different syntax.

Comment: I am not getting, Can you give more details  on input to your code and respective output?

Comment: Include how are you first calling the recursive function

Comment: this is the input  
`vvi=[]
for i in range(5):
 fn([],i)`

Comment: And the expected output?

Comment: first thing in learning...use good variable names, alphabets as variables should be limited for count loops!!!

Comment: the expected output is 
`vvi=[[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,2],[1,4],[2,3],[5]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to reconsider the recursive solution and consider a dynamic programming approach:

```
def fn(N):
    ways = {0:[[]]}
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        for i, x in enumerate(range(n, N+1)):
            for v in ways[i]:
                ways.setdefault(x, []).append(v+[n])
    return ways[N]

>>> fn(5)
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [5]]
>>> fn(3)
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [3]]
```

Using `global` variables and side effects on input parameters is generally consider bad practice and you should look to avoid.

Comment: I believe I mention this in the first sentence of my post.

Comment: It actually doesn't return duplicate solutions if only elements amtter and not their order so +1

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to just formulate it as a recursive description and implement it. You want to prepend all singleton [`j`] to each of the lists with sum `N-j`, unless `N-j=0` in which you also would include the singleton itself. Translated into python this would be

```
def glist(listsum, minelm=1):
    for j in range(minelm, listsum+1):
        if listsum-j > 0:
            for l in glist(listsum-j, minelm=j):
                yield [j]+l
        else:
            yield [j]

for l in glist(5):
    print(l)
```

The solution contains a mechanism that will exclude permutated solutions by requiring the lists to be non-decreasing, this is done via the `minelm` argument that limits the values in the rest of the list. If you wan't to include permuted lists you could disable the `minelm` mechanism by replacing the recursion call to `glist(listsum-j)`.

As for your code I don't really follow what you're trying to do. I'm sorry, but your code is not very clear (and that's not a bad thing only in python, it's actually more so in C).

First of all it's a bad idea to return the result from a function via a global variable, returning result is what `return` is for, but in python you have also `yield` that is nice if you want to return multiple elements as you go. For a recursive function it's even more horrible to return via a global variable (or even use it) since you are running many nested invocations of the function, but have only one global variable.

Also calling a function `fn` taking arguments `v` and `n` as argument. What do that actually tell you about the function and it's argument? At most that it's a function and probably that one of the argument should be a number. Not very useful if somebody (else) is to read and understand the code.

If you want an more elaborate answer what's formally wrong with your code you should probably include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the expected output (and perhaps observed output).

Comment: He is using a global variable to store the result, which is a horrible practice

Comment: @Adirio I didn't realize that, but I agree that's horrible - so I've updated the answer pointing out what I could read as being wrong in his solution. At least the more important points.

Comment: You may want to reconsider your arg name `sum` it's generally not a good idea to hide python builtins.

Comment: @AChampion I realized that, but didn't come up with a better name, but perhaps `listsum` is better. However I don't generally (in all cases) agree that it's a big no-no to do so.